# Dynamically change datatables background color

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Can't change datatables background color using jquery. I tried to show example below but when you run it, it's not really representative of the problem. I need to change the background of the whole table to black when user clicks something. I figured out this one line that changes some of the cells but not others. Also, the cells change back when the table is refreshed of data. Not good solution for both those reasons.

```js
jQuery('#tablepress-1_wrapper  td:gt(0)').css('background-color', '#000000');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tablepress-1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="dataTables_length" id="tablepress-1_length"><label>Show <select name="tablepress-1_length" aria-controls="tablepress-1" class=""><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div>
  <div id="tablepress-1_filter"
    class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="tablepress-1" type="search"></label></div>
  <table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1 dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="tablepress-1_info" style="width: 1203px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <caption style="caption-side:bottom;text-align:left;border:none;background:none;margin:0;padding:0;"><a href="https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tablepress&amp;action=edit&amp;table_id=1">Edit</a></caption>
    <tbody>

      <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">Promise Strategy</td>
        <td>Bitmex</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0.00000000</td>
        <td>1h:38m</td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash delIns" value="13"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 361px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending"></th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 155px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 53px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 245px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 163px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 58px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div class="dataTables_info" id="tablepress-1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries</div>
  <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="tablepress-1_paginate"><a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="tablepress-1" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="tablepress-1_previous">Previous</a><span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="tablepress-1" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></span>
    <a
      class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="tablepress-1" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" id="tablepress-1_next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your javascript code is telling to apply background color to all the "td" with index bigger than 0. You want to apply the background color to the table or the td?

Comment: I want to apply it to the whole table

Answer (score 0):

Manage the style with CSS. Create a class for the background color (ex.: *.backBackground*) and append it to the table with jQuery like this:

```
$('#tablepress-1').addClass('blackBackground');
```

You can easily remove it like this:

```
$('#tablepress-1').removeClass('blackBackground');
```

You CSS new class looks like this:

```
.blackBackground{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Here is a working copy -> https://jsfiddle.net/rk2gayse/6/

Comment: @xendi just fixed the selector and added a working example.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that but for some reason, it doesn't work on my page. I'm not sure why.

Comment: You can see it by visiting this link and going to Bot Commander:  http://inx.lv/0pt

Comment: You have this CSS selector applied to td overwriting the style -> .tablepress .odd td . Add this new body.wp-night-mode-on .tablepress td with the background